# cron job on codeigniter password protected site

Tags: codeigniter, cron, cpanel

Hey guys hope you could help me out

I am trying to get a cron job to work with a codeigniter application but its just not happening. I have cpanel and ftp access.

The site is password protected. I have been googling for a long time with no luck.

I dont really know linux, and although I do intend to atleast learn the basics of linux commands later, but for now I just want a simple cron job to work.

basically to test the cron job, I have a method

```
public function update_cronjob2() {     
    $to = "my_email@domain.com";
    $subject = "asdf!";
    $message="cronjob";

    mail($to,$subject,$message);
}
```

when I enter the url directly,i.e

```
http://www.site.com/my_directory/index.php/home/update_cronjob2
```

I get the email. but not with cron jobs.

This is what I have tried so far. Note that I have pasted everything as-is and only replaced the text for username, password and site. no symbols, etc added

```
wget --user='user123'--password='pass123' http://www.site.com/my_directory/index.php/home/update_cronjob2
```

AND

```
wget http://www.site.com/my_directory/index.php/home/update_cronjob2
```

and

```
$ cd /my_directory/project;$ php index.php home update_cronjob2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible for you to place the cron outside the admin/user part of the site? It sounds like you need to be logged in to access given page. That's why your browser can handle it, but not the cron.

That, or you could do add this in your login part:

```
if ( ! in_array($this->uri->segment(1), array('cron'))) {
    // Login prompt
}
```

Or maybe you have some other issue?

Comment: sorry I dont really know much about cron jobs. I just added it via cpanel. How exactly do you view the errors messages for a cron job?

Comment: I've never tried, nor been needing to know how to do that. Try using [output](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#output) or [logging](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html) to achieve what you want. In theory try open the url in another webbrowser. The result should be equal.